# FFFTP接続でhttpdocsの直下に配置したファイルがサイトで表示されないです。

Tags: apache, ftp, vsftpd

大変お世話になっております。どうかお教え願いませんでしょうか。

CentOS6、Apache、mysql、FFFTPをインストール後、FFFTPでhttpdocsというフォルダを自作し、その直下にファイルを配置してもサイトで表示されない状態になっております。

多分、vsftpdのインストール/設定、Apahceのインストール/設定に問題があるものと考えておりますが、この様な場合、どこに問題があるかお教え願いませんでしょうか。

＊ドメインの設定、ポート80の開放は正しく行われたと思います。

＊httpd.confに設定されている/var/www/html、あるいは/var/www/vhosts/ドメイン名/httpdocsと、FFFTPのhttpdocsの関連付けの様な設定がなされていないのであろうと考えております。

＊ドメイン名をURLウィンドウにタイプし、エンターを押すとApache 2 Test Pageのページが表示されます。

＊ FFFTPで以下の様にhttpdocs直下にファイルを配置しても、表示されるべきページが表示されず、以下のエラーが表示されます。

```
FFFTP：/httpdocs/index.php
URL：ドメイン名/index.php

Not Found
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at xxxxxx.com Port 80
```

＊SSH接続で、以下の様にファイルを配置すると、ドメイン名/index.phpでindex.phpに記載されているページが表示されます。

```
ssh接続：/var/www/html/index.php
URL：ドメイン名/index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apacheで設定したドキュメントルートが`/var/www/html`であるなら、方法は何でも構いませんが
指定のディレクトリ以下にファイルを配置しないとwebページとして認識されません。

取りうる対応の選択肢として

1. 初めからFFFTP接続時、`/var/www/html`に対してファイルを転送する。
2. あなたが作成した`/httpdocs/`ディレクトリに転送したファイルを`/var/www/html`以下に移動する。
3. `/var/www/html`ディレクトリに対するシンボリックリンク`/httpdocs`として作成する。

Comment: cubick様、ご回答感謝いたします。
色々と試した結果、現時点の問題点は、FFFTPでサーバーＡからサーバーＢにファイルを移行した際に、FFFTP右側に表示される所有者が10000から0に変更され、Server Error 403 Forbiddenというエラーが表示されているようなのですが、エラーが表示されない様にサーバーＢの所有者も10000になる様に設定するにはどうれすればよろしいかお分かりになりますでしょうか？

Comment: コメントの内容は元質問からは大きく外れたものに見えるので、必要に応じて別質問として投稿してください。

Answer (score 1):

FFFTPでアップロードしたファイルの属性を変更してみてください。

オーナー： 呼出、書込
グループ： 呼出
その他： 呼出

ご参考）[FFFTPヘルプ](https://ja.osdn.net/projects/ffftp/wiki/%E3%83%98%E3%83%AB%E3%83%97%2F%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%2F%E5%B1%9E%E6%80%A7%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4)

Comment: take88様、お時間を頂きまして感謝いたします。いろいろ試した結果、インストール時に付与するユーザーの権限に依存しているらしいという認識です。